# How to use a dongle as HotSpot on Linux?

Tags: linux, wifi, internet, wifi-hotspot

I'm running Linux on a virtual machine on MAC OS. Currently, I've written a script to use a dongle to connect to a WiFi network and use web services.

Now, I am looking to use my dongle as a WiFi Hotspot. So my wearable device can connect to my dongle and use the internet.

Is it possible to do that?

Hardware Details are:

1. The dongle is a ZyDAS USB 2.0
2. I'm using VMWare Fusion to run Linux
3. Linux version (Ubuntu 12.04) :

   **Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-42-generic #62~precise1-Ubuntu**
4. I'm using the following python script to connect from Linux to the Wifi:

   **/usr/share/checkbox/scriptsss/create_connection**

Comment: Please provide the hardware maker's name of this dongle along with versions etc. Also what VM software are you using and what distro of Linux are you running. It's generally best if you include as much useful details such as these when asking Q's here so that other's can provide you the best help possible.

Comment: Dongle information is ZyDAS USB 2.0 and manufacturer is TP-Link.  I am using VMWare Fusion to run Linux. Right now, I am using a Python script to connect from Linux to Wifi Network....

Comment: What's the version of Linux?

Comment: Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-42-generic #62~precise1-Ubuntu